# Changing chat type

Tags: c#, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

I have WTelegramClient and I need to change the chat(group,supgroup) from public to private chat
,I am tried to find solutions in the WTelegramClient but I don't find it ..

I am tried to changing chat type from public to private chat using WTelegramClient, but I can not it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try `Channels_UpdateUsername(channel, null)`

Side note: **DON'T WRITE comments on random Github commits** requesting new features to be added to the library, especially after I told you in Github Issues that it was no a library problem but rather a question about using Telegram API correctly.
Next time, I will report the abuse.

Comment: I didn't know I'm sorry,
Can you help me to change the group type from public to private?